# How to remove footer credits injected by a plugin in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

This is my website: https://washburnhome.com/

A plugin is adding credits in the footer. It's appended into the dom via JS.

You can go to site and check the live badge and code. However, the CSS code I added to remove the class is not working.

```
.MDow-1{display:none !important;}
```

The JS code injected by the plugin:

```
  var template = document.getElementById("MDow-1");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important; clear: both !important".replace(/\s/g, " ".repeat(parseInt(Math.random() * 29 + 1))));
  var shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: "closed"});
  shadow.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks a code that is supposed for going against author rights

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying:

```
.MDow-1 { height: 0; }
```

This could provide another solution instead of trying to override the display: block! important on the tag.

But in reality if the plugin requires you to credit it in order to use then you should probably leave it or find another alternative.